# HAProxy Active Directory - how to address "hostname does not match common name in certificate" error

Tags: proxy, active-directory, ldap, haproxy

I have a number of applications that can only point at a single Active Directory server for LDAP authentication.  To provide redundancy in the authentication I have been working on a solution to proxy the domain servers in the event of a server failure or outage due to maintenance.

I have an HAProxy configuration working

```
frontend ad_fe
    log global
    bind *:636
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    default_backend ad_be

backend ad_be
    log global
    mode tcp
    server server01 server01.mydomain.net:636 ca-file /certs/ad_ca_cert.crt check
    server server02 server02.mydomain.net:636 ca-file /certs/ad_ca_cert.crt check
    server server03 server03.mydomain.net:636 ca-file /certs/ad_ca_cert.crt check backup

    option       tcp-check
    tcp-check    connect port 636 ssl
    tcp-check    send-binary 300c0201          # LDAP bind request "<ROOT>" simple
    tcp-check    send-binary 01                # message ID
    tcp-check    send-binary 6007              # protocol Op
    tcp-check    send-binary 0201              # bind request
    tcp-check    send-binary 03                # LDAP v3
    tcp-check    send-binary 04008000          # name, simple authentication
    tcp-check    expect binary 0a0100          # bind response + result code: success
    tcp-check    send-binary 30050201034200    # unbind request
```

The proxy server is working, the SSL passthrough is working.  The problem is that my LDAP queries are now directed to the proxy and when the LDAP server receives the request and fails to match the hostname to the cert giving the error
`TLS: hostname (proxy.mydomain.net) does not match common name in certificate`

I can update the local hosts file to map the correct server name to the proxy, but when server2 or server3 is hit it still fails.

Is there a way to rewrite the server FQDN so that the LDAP server receives the correct hostname?  This is not running in HTTP mode so the usual header rewrites are not there and I have not been able to find another way.  Is HAProxy the best tool for the job?